# When using cfmail, a reply to a message contains reply-to

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfmail

Our clients send newsletters to their users. The code that transmits the message is as follows:

```
<cfmail to="First Last <recipientemail>" from="Sender <noreply@ourdomain.com>" failto="noreply@ourdomain.com" subject="Any subject" type="HTML">
<cfmailparam name="Reply-To" value="adifferentemail@whateverdomain.com">        
message
</cfmail>
```

Here's what's odd:

- The mail is sent.
- The recipient receives the message successfully.
- Recipient replies, adifferentemail@whateverdomain.com receives their reply.
- When the owner of adifferentemail@whateverdomain.com tries to reply to their reply, the email address of the recipient is the original "from address"(noreply@ourdomain.com). So they are unable to reply b/c its not the recipient's actual address.

I am at a loss for what is causing this.

Here is a screenshot of the attempt to reply to the reply. 
http://postimg.org/image/7dqmo0dd3/

Comment: is there reason you're not using the "replyto" attribute of the cfmail tag? https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-m-o/cfmail.html

Comment: yes, to avoid spam filters. if they want to reply to the sender (whose email is not of our domain) i need to use the reply to

Comment: No, I don't think you understood my question.  I know what a reply to is.  I asked why you're adding a cfmailparam instead of just using the built-in replyTo attribute that's natively supported by the cfmail tag.  It's possible your cfmailparam is conflicting somehow, but you'd need to inspect the headers of one of your messages to know.

Comment: Oh, yes i've tried both methods. Both methods have produced this odd scenario.

Comment: Not sure then. It sounds like you should focus on the initial recipient's E-mail client as I think that's where it's getting bungled.  Look at the headers in that second message (that doesn't involve CFMail) for clues.